# DAX syntax - Countrows using allexcept filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am using three different measures in the same visual (clustered column chart), but in one of the measures I want to leave out the filter which is used in the other measures. That's why I can't use filter on visual because in one of the measures I don't want this to be used.

I am counting rows, a specific number in 'x_channel' column, but I only want to count rows that 'does not contain "3-"' from column "associate.name" in the same table (TICKET).

How do I add this filter in the following syntax:

```
E-post = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET), TICKET[x_channel]=2, USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet], TICKET[Created]))
```

I think the syntax should be something like this:

```
E-post = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET), TICKET[x_channel]=2 && ALLEXCEPT(TICKET, TICKET[ASSOCIATE.name]="3-"), USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet], TICKET[Created]))
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of `ALLEXCEPT` is totally different. According to the docs and [dax.guide](https://dax.guide/allexcept/)

> ALLEXCEPT - Returns all the rows in a table except for those rows that are affected by the specified column filters.

So with this function, you can manipulate filter context to remove all filters from the given table but still keep filters from the column provided to `ALLEXCEPT` function.

The syntax would be like

```
Measure = 
   CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS( TABLE1 ),
      ALLEXCEPT( TABLE2, TABLE2[ColumnName] )
   )
```

For your case, try this one:

```
E-post = 
   CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS( TICKET ), 
      TICKET[x_channel] = 2,
      TICKET[ASSOCIATE.name] <> "3-", 
      USERELATIONSHIP( DIM_DATO[Opprettet], TICKET[Created] )
   )
```

or you can use `FILTER` with `ALL` and then `COUNTROWS` as follows

```
E-post = 
   CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS(, 
         FILTER(
            ALL( TICKET ),
            TICKET[x_channel] = 2 && TICKET[ASSOCIATE.name] <> "3-"
         )
      ),
      USERELATIONSHIP( DIM_DATO[Opprettet], TICKET[Created] )
   )
```

In fact, the `FILTER` with `ALL` is used under the hood in the first scenario.

Comment: Thanks for input! I thought of an alternative solution, instead of using filter in dax syntax I will just filter the table. Then I could just use ALL function in the measure where I need to ignore this filter. But I still get the wrong measure, is there something missing in my syntax: 

Telefon = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET), ticket[x_channel]=2, ALL(TICKET[ASSOCIATE.name]), USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet], TICKET[Created]))

Comment: Use the measure without filter (the first one). It should yield the proper result.

Comment: I think I already know what you want. Remove the ALL part from the measure. Put viz and grab ASSOCIATE.name field in the filter pane. Then it should work as expected.

Comment: I got the result I wanted. Thank you!